# jinja2 ansible - accessing complex var

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I've spent hours trying to template a `.pgpass` file given a fairly complex variable structure. I think I need a nested "for" loop to access what I need, but I'm not sure how to drill down properly.

Here's the var:

```
clients:
  - client1:
      postgres_users:
        - name: user1
          pass: mypassword1
        - name: user3
          pass: mypassword2
      postgres_user_priv_ssh_key: |   
        a
        multiline
        var
      postgres_user_pub_ssh_key: "ssh-rsa blahblahblah"
  - client2:
      postgres_users:
        - name: user3
          pass: mypassword3
        - name: user4
          pass: mypassword4
      postgres_user_priv_ssh_key: |   
        a.n.other
        multiline
        var
      postgres_user_pub_ssh_key: "ssh-rsa blahblahblahdeblah"
```

The `.pgpass` file is of the format:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

So, for each "client" under "clients", I need to iterate through and render the `name` and `pass` of each one. I've tried so many iterations of the jinja2 template, that it's probably not worth putting any down here, as none of them worked :) I'm open to restructuring the data in some way, but I feel that that's a fairly good way to structure it, as it may need to be read by multiple machines for other purposes (one to many?)

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: on `client1` and `client2` you have two accounts, each account should have its own line in the produced file? what about the values for `hostname:port:database`? where their values should be picked up from?

Comment: Very good point, I had to go and think about that :) "hostname" will be the `clients` list (e.g. client1, client2), port will be 5432 (or `*` as default). For the purposes of this problem, you can assume that these users will also be allowed access to all DBs, so a `*` there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a playbook/template. please note some changes done in the variable structure. More specifically, the `clients` is not a list variable anymore. added 2 more variables for `db_name` and `db_port` as well:

```
---
- name: test play
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  become: yes
  vars:
    db_port: 5432
    db_name: "*"
    clients:
      client1:
        postgres_users:
          - name: user1
            pass: mypassword1
          - name: user3
            pass: mypassword2
        postgres_user_priv_ssh_key: |   
          a
          multiline
          var
        postgres_user_pub_ssh_key: "ssh-rsa blahblahblah"
      client2:
        postgres_users:
          - name: user3
            pass: mypassword3
          - name: user4
            pass: mypassword4
        postgres_user_priv_ssh_key: |   
          a.n.other
          multiline
          var
        postgres_user_pub_ssh_key: "ssh-rsa blahblahblahdeblah"

  tasks:
  - name: run the template
    template:
      src: templates/testt.j2
      dest: /tmp/testt.txt
```

jinja template:

```
{% for db_client in lookup('dict', clients) %}
{% for user in clients[db_client.key].postgres_users %}
{{ db_client.key }}:{{ db_port }}:{{ db_name }}:{{ user.name }}:{{ user.pass }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

result:

```
[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]# cat /tmp/testt.txt        
client1:5432:*:user1:mypassword1
client1:5432:*:user3:mypassword2
client2:5432:*:user3:mypassword3
client2:5432:*:user4:mypassword4
[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]#
```

hope it helps

Comment: I went with this one in the end, as the dictionary approach could possibly leave more flexibility if I need to go back and add things later. Many thanks, I have been trying to solve this for ages :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

.

```
> cat create-pgpass.yml
- hosts: localhost                                                                           
  become: yes                                                                                
  become_method: sudo                                                                        
  become_user: root                                                                          
  vars:                                                                                      
    pg_hostname: srv.example.com                                                             
    pg_port: 5432                                                                            
    pg_database: db001                                                                       
    pg_clients:                                                                              
      - client1:                                                                             
        postgres_users:                                                                      
          - name: user1                                                                      
            pass: mypassword1                                                                
          - name: user3                                                                      
            pass: mypassword2                                                                
        postgres_user_priv_ssh_key: |                                                        
            a                                                                                
            multiline                                                                        
            var                                                                              
        postgres_user_pub_ssh_key: "ssh-rsa blahblahblah"                                    
      - client2:                                                                             
        postgres_users:                                                                      
          - name: user3                                                                      
            pass: mypassword3                                                                
          - name: user4                                                                      
            pass: mypassword4                                                                
        postgres_user_priv_ssh_key: |                                                        
            a.n.other                                                                        
            multiline                                                                        
            var                                                                              
        postgres_user_pub_ssh_key: "ssh-rsa blahblahblahdeblah"                              
  tasks:                                                                                     
    - template:                                                                              
        src: /scratch/pgpass.j2                                                              
        dest: /scratch/.pgpass
```

.

```
> cat /scratch/pgpass.j2
{% for item in pg_clients %}
{% for user in item.postgres_users %}
{{ pg_hostname }}:{{ pg_port }}:{{ pg_database }}:{{ user.name }}:{{ user.pass }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

.

```
> ansible-playbook create-pgpass.yml
PLAY [localhost] 
****************************************************************************
TASK [Gathering Facts] 
**********************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
TASK [template] 
*****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
PLAY RECAP
*****************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

.

```
> cat /scratch/.pgpass 
srv.example.com:5432:db001:user1:mypassword1
srv.example.com:5432:db001:user3:mypassword2
srv.example.com:5432:db001:user3:mypassword3
srv.example.com:5432:db001:user4:mypassword4
```