# Ansible : How to get a specific vars on a nested vars

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to figure out how I can get a specific var only and get its value in a nested/complex vars

I have this snippet on my ansible role *default/main.yml*

```yaml
disk_additional_disks:
   - disk: "/dev/sdb"
     fstype: xfs
     mount_options: rw,nodev,noatime,nobarrier,inode64
     mount: "{{ gp_data_mount_point }}"
     vgname: "{{gp_lvm_vg_name }}"

   - disk: "/dev/sdc"
     fstype: xfs
     mount_options: rw,nodev,noatime,nobarrier,inode64
     mount: "{{ gp_data_mount_point }}"
     vgname: "{{gp_lvm_vg_name }}"

   - disk: "/dev/sdd"
     fstype: xfs
     mount_options: rw,nodev,noatime,nobarrier,inode64
     mount: "{{ gp_data_mount_point }}"    
     vgname: "{{gp_lvm_vg_name }}"
```

What Im trying is to get only the values of `disk` which is `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`, `/dev/sdd`

And created a playbook which prints into one line

```yaml
- name: Show  disk
  debug:
     msg: "{{ item| json_query('[].disk') }}" 
  with_items: "{{ disk_additional_disks }}"
```

Assuming output is:

```
'/dev/sdb','/dev/sdd','/dev/sdc'
```

or

```
/dev/sdb,/dev/sdd,/dev/sdc
```

Can anyone help me as I am really struggling to solve this.

I also looked on similar issues, but I want to achieve it using playbook

- [jinja2 ansible - accessing complex var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982925/jinja2-ansible-accessing-complex-var)
- [How to create/join vars in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142633/how-to-create-join-vars-in-ansible)

Comment: Posting an anonymized version of you variable `disk_additional_disks` would help answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout ansible documentation for nested variable loops [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#comparing-loop-and-with).

Roles are not expose default variables by default to the playbook. You can check out these threads for more information: [thread1](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/33768), [thread2](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/21890)

Also as @VladimirBotka pointed out you can expose them with using `public: true` parameter with `include_role`.

But if you want to hardcode it you can use `include_vars` to include them in your playbook explicitly. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html).

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars: "roles/your-role/defaults/main.yml"
    - name: Show  disk
      debug:
        msg: "{{ disk_additional_disks|subelements('disk') }}"
```

Comment: Quoting: *"Roles do not expose default variables to the playbook"*. By default, they don't. It's optional. See [public](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#parameter-public).

Comment: @VladimirBotka Thank you! I I have not seen that.

Answer (score 0):

Use either *[`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#map)* or *[`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter)*. Both tasks below give the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ disk_additional_disks|
                 map(attribute='disk')|
                 list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ disk_additional_disks|
                 json_query('[].disk') }}"
```

(json_query needs installation of [JMESPATH](https://jmespath.org/)).